# My computer stays stuck on the acer screen

Tags: boot

I have an Acer Aspire 5532. The night before it began to have problems i just shut the lid for sleep mode. The next day i go to turn it on, and the black Acer screen comes up but it freezes there. I can sometimes manage to press F2 but it just says please wait and freezes. Can i get a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try and unplug the laptop from the power cord, then remove the battery. Leave it out for a few minutes, put it back and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot off a windows setup disk and run startup repair?

You can try resetting the CMOS too, although it may be harder to do so in a laptop. See if you can run Memtest to test your RAM.

Comment: The Acer screen indicates it freezes in the POST... So no, I don't think he'll be able to boot from a disk...

Comment: I see, my mistake.